# how to get updated list more natural and not use flag

Tags: python, list

I have two list which is

```
old_list = [{"tag": "apple","value":4}, {"tag": "orange","value":5}]
new_list = [{"tag": "apple","value":1}, {"tag": "orange","value":2}, {"tag": "grape","value":3}]
```

I want a `new_list`,which if new_list's `item['tag']` equal old_list's `item['tag']`, `new_list['value']` equals `old_list['value']`, if new_list has new item,
then `new_list['value']` initialize 0.

which the result:

```
new_list = [{"tag": "apple","value":4}, {"tag": "orange","value":5}, {"tag": "grape","value":0}]
```

here is my implement:

```
old_list = [{"tag": "apple","value":4}, {"tag": "orange","value":5}]
new_list = [{"tag": "apple","value":1}, {"tag": "orange","value":2}, {"tag": "grape","value":3}]
update_list = []
for new in new_list:
    flag_new_item = True
    for old in old_list:
        if new["tag"] == old['tag']:
            new["value"] = old['value']
            flag_new_item = False
            break
    if flag_new_item:
        new['value'] = 0
print(new_list)
```

since I use 2'times iterator to implement the problem, which i think too slow and non-python style , plus I introduce new flag which look like not so good.
is there a more directed ,convenient,efficient way to implement it

Comment: Obvious point and maybe you cannot but perhaps earlier in you code could you build the dictionaries without the "tag" and "value" keys. i.e. it would be much easier with dictionaries like: {"apple":1, "orange":2, "grape":3}

Comment: okay this structure is more easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `tag` to `value` dictionary from `old_list` and update `new_list` items appropriately:

```
old_list = [{"tag": "apple","value":4}, {"tag": "orange","value":5}]
new_list = [{"tag": "apple","value":1}, {"tag": "orange","value":2}, {"tag": "grape","value":3}]

# create a dictionary from old_list
old_tags = {i['tag']: i['value'] for i in old_list}

# update new_list with old_list values if present
for item in new_list:
    item['value'] = old_tags.get(item['tag'], 0)

print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
[{'tag': 'apple', 'value': 4}, {'tag': 'orange', 'value': 5}, {'tag': 'grape', 'value': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension having a dictionary comprehension within, and use conditions too:

```
print([{k:(next(iter(old_list[idx:idx+1]),{}).get(k,0) if k=='value' else v) for k,v in i.items()} for idx,i in enumerate(new_list)])
```

Use `enumerate` first then loop, then have a dictionary comprehension with a condition for the value, and get the `old_list`'s value if able to.

Comment: Clever, perhaps, but far from best practice and by no means readable or helpful.

Comment: Sometimes you can end up trying to squeeze too much into a single line.

Comment: Next time i'll pay attention guys.